# How to not push a segue into the Nav Controller Stack?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, stack, storyboard

I would like to know what kind of trick to use for "not pushing" a view controller into the navigation controller stack (iOS)

I have this : 
If user is not logged, show view A then show B
If user is logged, show B 

As I am using the storyboard, I used a performSegue if the user is logged so he goes directly to B. But with this method, the Navigation Controller gets a push of view A in the stack. 

I was thinking of poping out a level of the stack in some void (but I don't know how to do this).
I was also thinking of not pushing the view into the nav controller stack (but I don't know how to do this).

Thanks

Update :

I tried this :

```
//The view B
TabBarMain* mainViewController = [[TabBarMain alloc] init];
//If already logged in
if([username length] == 0)
{
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainViewController];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];
}
```

The problem of this code is that it shows me a black screen (doesn't crash). It seems that I need to init something and I have nothing in my TabBarMain.m, I don't know what to write in there. This TabBarMain is linked to the Tab Bar Controller of the Storyboard.
Is there no other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size in your rootViewController's viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSArray *viewControllers

    if (logged) {
        NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:viewControllerB];
    } else {
        NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:viewControllerA];
    }

    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];
}
```

Since your viewController is linked in Storyboard and not instantiated in code you need to instantiate it from the storyboard not your empty code. Make sure the identifier matches the identifier for your ViewController in your storyboard.

```
TabBarMain *mainViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarMain"];
```

Comment: I tried this (updated my post) but doesn't really work ... =S

Comment: If TabBarMain is linked to a Storyboard view you need to init from the storyboard not the basic init function. I've added to my answer.